# Sum across columns and rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sum, sap-ase

Consider a table like this

```
table
+--------+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+
| BookId | ItemId1 | Quantity1 | ItemId2 | Quantity2 |
+--------+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+
|      1 |       1 |         2 |       2 |         1 |
|      1 |       3 |         1 |       2 |         1 |
|      2 |       1 |         1 |       2 |         1 |
+--------+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+
```

Now I want to get the sum of columns quantity for each item grouped by book. How can I take the sum across different columns then? right now I use an awkward solution like building a temporary table and then querying this one, but it must be possible in a more elegant way!?

```
select
    BookId 'BookId',
    ItemId1 'ItemId',
    Quantity1 'Quantity'
into #temptab
from table
union all
select
    BookId,
    ItemId2,
    Quantity2
from table
```

and after that

```
select 
    BookId,
    ItemId,
    sum(Quantity)
from #temptab
group by ItemId, BookId
```

How can I get rid of this intermediate step?

Desired output:

```
+--------+--------+----------+
| BookId | ItemId | Quantity |
+--------+--------+----------+
|      1 |      1 |        2 |
|      1 |      3 |        1 |
|      1 |      2 |        2 |
|      2 |      1 |        1 |
|      2 |      2 |        1 |
+--------+--------+----------+
```

Comment: If ItemId1 matches ItemId2, do you want them to add together?

Comment: Use the UNPIVOT command.

Comment: You should design your data model to reflect the *data* rather than a spreadsheet or some kind of physical form. Having repeating groups of columns is usually a bad sign. Is there anything, inherently, that is different about an `ItemId1` vs an `ItemId2`? If so, why are you now trying to treat them identically for this query? If not, why isn't there just a single `ItemId` and `Quantity` column and just more *rows* in the table?

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever You are right in principle. However, this is the data structure that I cannot change and have no influende in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `cross apply` with `table valued constructor` to `unpivot` the data then find `sum` per `bookid` and `item`.

This will avoid your intermediate step

```
SELECT BookId,
       item,
       Sum(quantity)
FROM   Youratble
       CROSS apply (VALUES(Quantity1,ItemId1),
                          (Quantity2,ItemId2))cs(quantity, item)
GROUP  BY BookId,
          item
```

As mentioned by Mikael Eriksson for `sql server 2005` use this

```
SELECT BookId,
       item,
       Sum(quantity)
FROM   Youratble
       cross apply 
            (select Quantity1, ItemId1 
             union all 
             select Quantity2, ItemId2) as cs(quantity, item)
GROUP  BY BookId,
          item
```

Comment: I messed up and put bookId in my cross apply. Deleted my solution and + 1

Comment: Thanks. However, I get an error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'values'." Seems like table valued constructor was only created in SQL Server 2008, I am using 2005. You have a solution for that also?

Comment: @WilliFischer Change to use union all instead `cross apply (select Quantity1, ItemId1 union all Quantity2, ItemId2) as cs(quantity, item)`

Comment: @ Mikael Eriksson But then I am using that subqueries again which I would like to avoid.

Comment: @WilliFischer - updated. FYI that is not a subquery.

Comment: If you don't mind, do you also know how to do that in Sybase ASE?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've done, you can do it in one single step using subqueries:

```
select 
combined.BookId,
combined.ItemId,
sum(combined.Quantity)
from 
  (select
   BookId 'BookId',
   ItemId1 'ItemId',
   Quantity1 'Quantity'
   from tableName
   union all
   select
   BookId,
   ItemId2,
   Quantity2
   from tableName) as combined
group by combined.ItemId, combined.BookId
```

Comment: I Would like to avoid the subquery. Thanks anyway